# Big query to find row count for unique visit where purchase is null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table

```
visit_num   visid_high  visid_low   visit_page_num  purchase
  1            123        456              1          null
  1            123        456              2           12
  2            123        556              1          null
  2            123        556              2          null
  2            123        556              3          null
  2            123        556              4          null
```

and wanted to get count of rows for unique visit_num+visid_high+visid_low where purchase is null. Here, visit_page_num is id of page user visited and visit is defined with concatenation of visid_high, visid_low and visit_num. I have written query to get row count where purchased is null, Below is the big query statement

```
SELECT
  COUNT(UNIQUE(CONCAT(STRING(visid_high), STRING(visid_low), STRING(visit_num)))) AS Visits,
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  purchased is null
```

and found row count is 2, which is wrong, it should be 1. This query gives row count for below row as well.

```
visit_num   visid_high  visid_low   visit_page_num  purchase
  1            123        456              1          null
```

However this visit comes with purchase value for visit_page_num id 2

```
visit_num   visid_high  visid_low   visit_page_num  purchase
  1            123        456              2          null
```

Can anyone help me to write this query to get row count for unique visit where purchase is null.
Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(Visit) AS Visits
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(STRING(visid_high), STRING(visid_low), STRING(visit_num)) AS Visit,
    COUNT(purchase) AS purchases
  FROM
    table_name
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING purchases = 0
)
```